# Kinect openni_launch TF2 exception warning

Tags: ros, kinect, tf2, openni-launch, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I tried to run other package with openni_launch of ASUS Xtion. In the launch file of other package, it subscribes to /camera/depth_registered/points, /camera/rgb/image_raw, /camera/depth_registered/image, and /camera/depth/camera_info.  When I launched roslaunch openni_launch openni.launch, it was fine. But when I launched the other package, I got this following warning repeating over and over and could not subscribe to kinect rostopics.

> [ WARN] [1412634733.035488109]: TF2
> exception: Invalid argument
> "/camera_rgb_optical_frame" passed to
> lookupTransform argument target_frame
> in tf2 frame_ids cannot start with a
> '/' like:

Anyone who has seen this warning before? I am using ubuntu 14.04 and ROS indigo. I did openni-related apt-gets and installed openni_launch. The version of my ASUS Xtion is old one, so openni_launch package is comparable with it, and I was able to subscribe all of rostopics properly, which is fine. It looks like TF2 related problem, but I do not know exactly why it happened.

Thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/194317/kinect-openni_launch-tf2-exception-warning/) by [yoo00](https://answers.ros.org/users/19901/yoo00/) on ROS Answers with karma: 25 on 2014-10-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Its because the launch file in openni_launch hasn't been updated to remove the slashes from the cameras frame_ids. You can edit the launch file openni.launch and remove the "/" from "/camera_rgb_optical_frame" (I cant remember exactly, but I think that launch file actually includes another file with a whole lot of parameters - which is the one you want to edit).

---

Originally posted by [James Diprose](https://answers.ros.org/users/3239/james-diprose/) with karma: 123 on 2014-10-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [yoo00](https://answers.ros.org/users/19901/yoo00/) on 2014-10-06**:
You're right! After I removed $(arg tf_prefix) prefixes in openni.launch file, it worked fine. Thank you James!

**Comment by [James Diprose](https://answers.ros.org/users/3239/james-diprose/) on 2014-10-06**:
No worries :)

**Comment by [Zari](https://answers.ros.org/users/22203/zari/) on 2015-06-09**:
Hello, I could not solve this problem, Will you kindly explain it in more clear way? I could not find $(arg tf_prefix) in openni.launch. In my openni.launch file it is like this <arg name="rgb_frame_id"   default="/$(arg camera)_rgb_optical_frame" />           Thanks

**Comment by [umair](https://answers.ros.org/users/25196/umair/) on 2016-06-13**:
Hi Zari, in the default value,
default="/$(arg camera)_rgb_optical_frame"/>
there is a '/' right after '='. You need to remove that. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The Indigo version was updated to remove the leading slashes. Unfortunately, that was not a backwards-compatible change.

For those still needing `tf_prefix`, use this new launch file:

```
roslaunch openni_launch openni_tf_prefix.launch tf_prefix:=your_namespace
```

See: https://github.com/ros-drivers/openni_launch/commit/b82104e0cda183450ab1171e5f4ed4597cb9cf6c

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2015-06-09

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1